# How to programatically send an application to background in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

I am developing a Windows Phone8 application and the moment application is launched I am doing certain functionality. But after that immediately I want to send the application to background/Close the application.

Means I want to simulate the Back Key functionality from code. Is there any provision for this?

Comment: How in a user experience point of view do you justify this ?

Comment: User only needs to see the splash screen to make sure application has started. Remaining functionality will be done in background.

Comment: Better try to display a state of the background process, even if it's not self explanatory of really useful. You may also let the user control that process for example ?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't force the user to close the app unexpectedly from your code. And don't go as far as throwing an unhandled exception and crashing the app, that's not very user-friendly.